# How to redefine a way that dependency properties get standardized values in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Nowdays I've faced a significant probelm of how and why dependency properties like `Margin` of `Textblock` can be set through different forms such as `"1,1,1,1"` and `"1,1"`, etc.

By another example, `Width` for `ColumnDefinition` can receive not numeric values that includes basically the `"*"` character or only has `"Auto"`, even though those `Width` property has the `GridLength` type and also its constructor is defined to have a `double` parameter and optionally `GridUnitType` so it absoultely needs to mediate between a normal `string` such as `"36*"` and a `GridLength` structure such as `new GridLength(36, GridUnitType.Star)`, but I have been really unable to find such process anywhere.

Now, here is my densed question to the words: how defiend is the work to convert them each other and can I declare any forms for my own custom dependency properties like the convertion to `Margin` and `Width` that I explained you?

Comment: This is done by TypeConverters, e.g. the [ThicknessConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.thicknessconverter) for objects of type Thickness (like Margin). A TypeConverter is registered by the TypeConerterAttribute of a type or a property declaration.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I'm greatly thankful of you and the other proposals.